# Stop form from closing conditionally

Tags: vb.net, return, vb.net-2010

My problem is that I don't know a suitable command to stop my code from running. If I use a return statement, like below, the code in the subroutine btnClose will keep running causing the program to close on an error. The form must not close if an error on saving occurs.

```
Private Sub Save_Customer()
   If txtName.text = "" then
       msgbox("Error")
       return
   End If
End sub

Private Sub btnClose_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
    save_Customer()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Sub to a Function, then evaluate the return:

```
Private Function Save_Customer() As Boolean
   If txtName.text = "" then
       msgbox("Error")
       return False
   Else
       Return True
   End If
End sub

Private Sub btnClose_Click(sender As System.Object, 
                  e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
    ' evaluate the return:
    If save_Customer() Then
        Me.Close()
    End IF
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You should better intercept `Closing` event, and `Cancel` closing via `e.Cancel = True`. Doing it otherwise would result in too much plumbing. (You can close the form **not only** via `btnClose`, right)? Also ALT+F4, Mouse click on X button etc. Be careful though, not to leave your user in a deadlock, where they cannot close your form, and have to fall back to using task manager.

Answer (score 0):

That is probably not the best way around your problem, but you could solve it like this:

```
Private Function Save_Customer()
     If txtName.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Error")
        Return False
    Else
        Return True
    End If

End sub

Private Sub btnClose_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles       btnClose.Click
    If Save_Customer() = False Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Me.Close()
    End if 
End Sub
End Class
```